# How can I subsett between two specific time points in r

Tags: r, time-series, subset

I have a question regarding subsetting or excluding data outside of specific time points of my data set. A small sample of my data set is below, which is already heavily subsetted from an original data frame of 12 000+ observations

[image]

So what I want to achieve is to be able to take a subset of this data between two specific time points e.g. between 13:30:00 and 19:30:00. The reason for this is I am looking to see the effects of outside temperature on activity of a beehive, with activity being a raw count of bees entering and exiting the hive.

At this stage I can subset between temperature ranges, date ranges etc. But I cannot subset for time. Would anyone have an idea of how to do this?

The code I was trying looks like this

```
x <- subset(beedata, Time >= 10:30:00 | Time <= 19:30:00, 
select=c(Date, Time, Activity, Outside.Temp))
```

However this gives me an error:

"1: In 10:30:0 : numerical expression has 21 elements: only the first used
2: In Ops.factor(Time, 10:30:0) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
3: In 19:30:0 : numerical expression has 12 elements: only the first used
4: In Ops.factor(Time, 19:30:0) : ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors".

It makes sense that >= isn't meaningful for factors, but I am unsure what to change this to for time. as.Date works for the dates, but as far as I can tell it doesn't work for time. As for only the first element used I don't understand that error. Hopefully this is clear.

Cheers
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why your data would be in factors, but with how its shown in your data I am assuming you should be able to convert a single element with

```
strptime(toString(*factor*))
```

Then from there, everything should be comparable as a date so something like the following should work

```
*date* >= strptime("13:30:00", "%H:%M:%S") & *date* <= strptime("19:30:00", "%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joseph, sorry for the slow reply its morning in my country. I have tried the first line of code and it gives me an error:  Error in strptime(toString("beedata$Time")) : 
  argument "format" is missing, with no default.

Comment: @Joseph Malecki I think I managed to figure out a solution to my problem in the end. It may not be the most efficient way, but this is the code I used is as follows: 

    beedata$Time <- as.character.POSIXt(beedata$Time).

bee <- filter(beedata, Time >= "10:30:00", Time <= "19:30:00").
bee1 <- filter(bee, Outside.Temp >= 20, Outside.Temp <= 25). Sorry about comment formatting, not sure how to format it cleaner